# How to dynamically change table cell color in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a view, where I am using ng-repeat to populate a table content with dynamic data.
Here's the code snippet-

```
    <tr ng-repeat="x in response">
        <td>{{x.property1}}</td>
        <td>{{x.property2}}</td>
        <td bgcolor="x.color1">{{x.property3}}</td>
        <td bgcolor="x.color2">{{x.property4}}</td>
    </tr>
```

But the table output is not changing. I am getting same color for every response. How do I actually alter the color? You can see the output in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxeVu.png). Also, the color that is present is not even supplied to the response.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive for this like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in response">
    <td>{{x.property1}}</td>
    <td>{{x.property2}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color1}">{{x.property3}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color2}">{{x.property4}}</td>
</tr>
```

DEMO:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('tableController', function($scope) {
  $scope.response = [{
      property1: 'Jill',
      property2: 'Smith',
      color1: 'red',
      color2: 'green'
    },
    {
      property1: 'John',
      property2: 'Doe',
      color1: 'yellow',
      color2: '#336699'
    },
  ];
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {padding: 10px; min-width:120px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-controller="tableController" ng-app="app">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in response">
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color1}">{{x.property1}}</td>
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color2}">{{x.property2}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-style` to change background color, With this you can bind any css style. please find documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in response">
  <td>{{x.property1}}</td>
  <td>{{x.property2}}</td>
  <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color1}">{{x.property3}}</td>
  <td ng-style="{'background-color': x.color2}">{{x.property4}}</td>
</tr>
```

Please find the example below of how can you use `ng-style` to set styles dynamically.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myName = {
    name: 'Dummy name',
    color1: 'white',
    color2: 'tomato',
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app="app">
  <p ng-style="{'background-color': myName.color2, 'color': myName.color1}">
  {{ myName.name }}
  </p>
</div>
```